# installing ubunutu in windows 8 laptop

Tags: 13.04

I am using Hp laptop with pre-installted Windows 8 operating system. I have upgraded my windows 8 to windows 8.1 recently. My question is can i install ubunutu in my laptop.
Please replay and help me to find a soluton.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/ Ubuntu 13.10 on to your Windows 8.1 laptop.
As long as your BIOS is set to the proper settings.

If secure boot is disabled, use a utility like UNetbootin or Win32diskimager to burn the Ubuntu .ISO to a USB drive.

If secure boot is still enabled, open up your BIOS settings during boot and look for things like Quick Boot, Launch COM, Secure Boot, anything close to that. And disable this. It will enable you to boot from Non-EFI devices. (e.g. USB drives, Legacy Operating Systems, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

First burn an USB key the usual way and insert it to your computer.

You then have to ask Windows to first go to UEFI, this is not easy, follow a guide like [this one](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-boot-uefi-bios-any-windows-81-tablet-or-device).

Then disable Fast Boot, Secure Boot, Launch COM (ask us if you hesitate on other option) but you must keep Launch CSM enabled !
Then save your changes and exit.

When it starts, you must press a key (try to press it as fast as you can, as many times as you can, it is a game you're playing), most of the time, this key is <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

You will then be prompted on which device you want to boot (sometimes including the UEFI setup), choose what looks like your USB key.
Then proceed the normal installation except that when you resize with GParted, you must be aware that the Partitioning system is most probably GPT, not MBR so you can have as many partition as you'd like, see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table) for more info.

At the end of the installation, go back to the UEFI and check that the priority is on GRUB and not Windows (I know normally it displays different disk and there are only one disk but this is UEFI, things have changed). Don't forget to reenable Secureboot (only disable it if you want to boot on the USB key).
Now several things may not work like, Grub not showing, Ubuntu not booting or Windows not booting. It is often the case but [Don't Panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2g2), if your Ubuntu is booting, boot on it or boot on the live USB and [install and run boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It should fix your problem :)